# Is there a usage of cross product with condition in relational algebra?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relational-algebra

I came across with a question in which cross product is used with a condition and it's not binary.

**X<sub>R.b=S.b</sub>(σ<sub>x="a"</sub>(S))**

What does it mean? How can it be translated into sql?

Comment: Please clarify how this is an SQL problem? Otherwise remove the tag.

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to read X in this case as a join between R and S (incidentally, cross product is equivalent to a natural join where the joined relations have no attributes in common). The notation is wrong however and I can't make sense of it. Assuming "X R.b=S.b" really means R JOIN S it's not clear to me how that relates to the restriction expression in parentheses.